# How to rename image at uploading on specific plugin or post-type in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, images, uploads

I am working on a plugin. In plugin, there is a custom media uploader. All images upload successfully.

Then I want that when I upload images its renamed, so i get this code and write it in my plugin file.

```
function foo_rename_image($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($filename, $ext);
    return "foo_".$name."_".date('dmy-his').$ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'foo_rename_image', 10);
```

It renamed images successfully when its uploaded. But there is one issue, its renamed all images.

**e.g.** My plugin creates a post type `products` and there is a custom media uploader so I upload an image its renamed, then I go to 'add post' or 'add page' and there I upload an image and its also renamed. I just want to rename images that uploaded by my plugin or custom post type.

So please give me an idea that when I upload images from my plugin or my custom post type then its renamed. Otherwise its upload default.